# How can you show EVERY emoji in a guild in one single embed?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm currently trying to create a code that will read all the emojis in the guild, then export it out onto one SINGLE embed. We did figure out how to call every emoji in the guild even with the animated ones, but it won't work on a SINGLE embed (it sends ONE emoji per embed) any help is appreciated!

I've tried using `while True:` but because it is a loop it will just go throughout the emojis and not stop.
Code:

```
@commands.command()
async def gimmeem(self, ctx):
      
        global j
        emojilist = ctx.guild.emojis
        bomber = (emojilist)[j]
        j += 1
        j =  0 if j == len(emojilist) else j
        
        emb = discord.Embed(title = "Server Emojis") #"You need help but here"
        emb.add_field(name = "Animated Emojis", value = f"{bomber} ")
        await ctx.send(embed=emb)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a for loop that runs through every emoji in the guild and adds the emoji to a description like this:

```py
@commands.command()
async def emoji(ctx):
   emojis = ctx.guild.emojis
   desc = ''
   for emoji in emojis:
      desc += str(emoji)
   await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title='Emojis',description=desc)
```

Comment: AWESOME!!!! it worked perfectly and I learned some new things! Take care! FYI you did need to add the self part in 
async def emoji (self,ctx):

Comment: @Derek if it was in a cog, you would need self. Glad to see a good question here :)

Comment: Well, he was using commands.command which should show I'm using it in a cog. He still didn't add self but I understand where you are going! @chess_lover_6